# python sort data structure by value lowest to highest

Tags: python

I'd like to sort a list of tuples by the magnitude of a unicode string, i.e. the first member of the tuple.

The "raw" tuples look like this:

**A**

```
[

   [
        (u'90000', 100318), 
        (u'21000', 58094), 
        (u'50000', 14695), 
        (u'250000', 8190), 
        (u'100000', 5718), 
        (u'40000', 4276)
     ]
]
```

After processing I'd like it to look like this:

**B**

```
[

   [
        (u'250000', 8190), 
        (u'100000', 5718), 
        (u'90000', 100318),
        (u'50000', 14695), 
        (u'40000', 4276),
        (u'21000', 58094)
     ]
]
```

I've tried some different approaches but I've not been able to get it to persist.

How to sort the list of tuples in **A** to render it like **B**?

Comment: Did you just copy-paste an email or chat conversation or something into the question box?

Comment: I don't see how the linked question is related *or* more general. Here you're sorting a list of tuples, there data is being read from a list of dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an interactive demonstration using `list.sort()`.

```
>>> help(list.sort)
Help on built-in function sort:

sort(...)
    L.sort(cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) -- stable sort *IN PLACE*;
    cmp(x, y) -> -1, 0, 1
```

The built-in help is useful but for a more complete explanation of the parameters we need to [consult the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

> cmp specifies a custom comparison function of two arguments (iterable elements) which should return a negative, zero or positive number depending on whether the first argument is considered smaller than, equal to, or larger than the second argument: cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(x.lower(), y.lower()). The default value is None.
>
> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element: key=str.lower. The default value is None (compare the elements directly).
>
> reverse is a boolean value. If set to True, then the list elements are sorted as if each comparison were reversed.

Continuing on:

```
>>> l = [[(u'90000', 100318),(u'21000', 58094),(u'50000', 14695),(u'250000', 8190),(u'100000', 5718),(u'40000', 4276)]]
>>> l[0].sort(key=lambda x:int(x[0]),reverse=True)
>>> l
[[(u'250000', 8190), (u'100000', 5718), (u'90000', 100318), (u'50000', 14695), (u'40000', 4276), (u'21000', 58094)]]
```

Comment: You could improve this answer by actually explaining how the code works and what a sort `key` is

Comment: Added doc link and excerpt

Comment: that's much better!

Answer (score 0):

Due to inner list, you need to dig into next layer => A[0]

Then use sort function with key & reverse to help you achieve the goal

```
list.sort(A[0], key= lambda x: int(x[0]), reverse=True)
```